# How to set the UserTokenProvider token expiration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

We're working on a new ASP.NET MVC 4.1 app. We're hooking up the ASP.NET Identity stuff, and we're struggling with tokens for password reset and new invite. I can't seem to find a way to set the expiration time for the tokens that are generated, and it seems to be set at around 10 mins by default. We're using a `EmailTokenProvider` as the user token provider, because it seems to work well with the security stamp on the user.

How can we set the expiration for the tokens - ideally we'd like to set it differently for the invite Vs the reset password tokens.

Our user manager looks like this:

```
var manager = new UserManager<User, long>(new UserStore(new UserRepository()));
manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<User, long>(manager) {AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false, RequireUniqueEmail = true};
manager.UserTokenProvider = new EmailTokenProvider<User, long>();
```

When a user requests a reset password link we call

`var token = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);` to get the token, and pass that on to the user.

When a user is invited, we call:

`var token = await _userManager.GenerateUserTokenAsync("FirstLogin", user.Id);`

to get the token, and send.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default implementations of the token providers in 2.0 don't allow you to change the token expiration, this is something we are considering for identity 3.0.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I found that using the `DataProtectorTokenProvider` was a better choice, for the longer lifetimes of tokens.

Comment: This is pretty worthless, there isn't even any documentation on this arbitrary expiry time.

Comment: @hao-kung can you please share what's the default reset password token expiration time?

Comment: 1 day, see https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin/DataProtectorTokenProvider.cs

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question well, following could help:

```
    private static string CalculateToken(User user)
    {
        byte[] time = BitConverter.GetBytes(DateTime.UtcNow.ToBinary());
        byte[] key = BitConverter.GetBytes(user.ID);
        string token = Convert.ToBase64String(time.Concat(key).ToArray());
        return token;
    }
```

And then:

```
   DateTime time = DateTime.FromBinary(BitConverter.ToInt64(data, 0));
   int id = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 8);

   if (time< DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-10) || user.ID != id)
            {
                //too old or IDs not matching
            }
```